# How to get link containing known text

Tags: javascript, yui

A page contains a link with the text "Open Help".  How to get the anchor containing that text with YUI?

Answer (score 0):

YUI2 provides therefore the getElementsBy function. It has a filter methode attribute and with it you can check if the current element matches your purpose. Notice that you get an array with all matched elements. So you can pick the first if there was a hit.
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.util.Dom.html#method_getElementsBy

```
var elements, 
    searchText = "Open Help";

elements = YAHOO.util.Dom.getElementsBy(function (element) {
    return (element.innerHTML === searchText) ? true : false;
}, "a", document);

if (elements.length > 0) {
    //do something with elements[0]
}
```

On the other hand the YUI3 solution is in my opinion a cleaner way:

```
var searchText = "Open Help";

Y.all("a").each(function (el) {
    if (el.getContent() === searchText) {
        //do something with the el
    }
});
```